# Making two types of same template compatible

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I do not know how to name the problem that I am facing. So I have a template class for matrices to accept different types e.g. int, double and other stuff. My problem is if I want to work on to different instance type of the class, I can not get it to compile. Here is the definition of the add function which supposedly should add a matrix to the current instance.

```
template <class T>
void Matrix<T>::add(const Matrix &m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this->rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->cols; ++j) {
            this->mat[i][j] += m.at(i,j);
        }
    }
}
```

It works just fine e.g. if I add a `Matrix<double>` to `Matrix<double>` instance.

But I can not get it to work, adding a `Matrix<int>` to a `Matrix<double>` e.g:

```
Matrix<double> matA(2,2);
Matrix<int> matB(2,2);
matA.add(matB);
```

The compiler (g++ 4.8) complains:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Matrix<double>::add(Matrix<int>&)
```

What can be the workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a class template, the template name is a shortcut for the current instantiation.  That is, `Matrix` is the same as `Matrix<T>`.  So by declaring `void add(const Matrix& m);` you say that you can add another matrix of the same type.

If you want the ability to add another matrix of an arbitrary type, you need to introduce another template parameter for it.

```
template <class T>
class Matrix {
    // ...
public:
    template <class U>
    void add(const Matrix<U>& m);
};

template <class T> template <class U>
void Matrix<T>::add(const Matrix<U>& m) {
    // ...
}
```